# elemMatch doesn't retrieve data from [ ] brackets in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Structure of collection:

```
{
  "address": {
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

The first query below doesn't return any results, second does. Why?
`"coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ]` Here coord is an array of two elements so why isn't elemMatch returning anything?

```
> db.restaurants.find({address : { $elemMatch: { coord: {$lt : -95.754168}}}});
> 
>
> db.restaurants.find({"address.coord" : {$lt : -95.754168}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed53c72c7494f71176bafb9"), "address" : { "building" : "3707", "coord" : [ -101.8945214, 33.5197474 ], "street" : "82 Street", "zipcode" : "11372" }, "borough" : "Queens", "cuisine" : "American ", "grades" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2014-06-04T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 12 }, { "date" : ISODate("2013-11-07T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "B", "score" : 19 }, { "date" : ISODate("2013-05-17T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "date" : ISODate("2012-08-29T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "date" : ISODate("2012-04-03T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 12 }, { "date" : ISODate("2011-11-16T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 7 } ], "name" : "Burger King", "restaurant_id" : "40534067" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed53c72c7494f71176bb325"), "address" : { "building" : "15259", "coord" : [ -119.6368672, 36.2504996 ], "street" : "10 Avenue", "zipcode" : "11357" }, "borough" : "Queens", "cuisine" : "Italian", "grades" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2014-09-04T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "date" : ISODate("2014-03-26T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 8 }, { "date" : ISODate("2013-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 10 }, { "date" : ISODate("2012-09-27T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 10 }, { "date" : ISODate("2012-04-20T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 7 }, { "date" : ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "C", "score" : 34 } ], "name" : "Cascarino'S", "restaurant_id" : "40668681" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed53c72c7494f71176bb7c8"), "address" : { "building" : "60", "coord" : [ -111.9975205, 42.0970258 ], "street" : "West Side Highway", "zipcode" : "10006" }, "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Japanese", "grades" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2014-03-20T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 9 }, { "date" : ISODate("2013-06-28T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "date" : ISODate("2012-07-05T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 13 }, { "date" : ISODate("2011-07-27T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 2 } ], "name" : "Sports Center At Chelsea Piers (Sushi Bar)", "restaurant_id" : "40882356" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason:

Your array doesn't contain valid element.

Smallest value in negative is the greatest value. So -73 is > than -95 and 40 is > -95.

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g--yogxF6It)

And other works. [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NEysrvOkN0f)

Both formats are valid. But data(mentioned coord) is also not matching the query in both the formats.

Comment: So why is the second query returning results?

Comment: That is returning other coords. Check your result. And second play link also. 4 different data you have.

Answer (score 1):

It is not finding the records because the schema would be different when translated.

For example: if you change your schema to the following, it will return the document:

```
{
  "address": [{
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  }],
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

Notice the square brackets around address sub-document.

Please follow this link for more reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents